# Can I enter the "restricted area" early in the game?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I generally like to work on side quests before the main quest.  So far I've started a couple (Bane's and Zsasz's quests, for instance) that have objectives inside a big red "restricted area" on the map.  I don't know what happens if I try to cross this boundary, as so far I haven't had reason to enter it.

Is it feasible to try to completely finish these side quests early in the story?  Or should I wait until I have access to this "restricted area" later in the game?  If I can't finish, is there any benefit to partially completing them now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not even possible to enter that until later in the game. There's a giant wall completely surrounding it.

[Side quests don't give any rewards except trophies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35899/do-side-missions-ever-affect-main-objective-in-batman-arkham-city)(except the first AR training mission or unless that's why he's doing it) and [with the exception of one trophy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33536/which-achievements-are-missable-in-batman-arkham-city), there's nothing that you can't do after beating the game.

Comment: You can't actually get into it really at all.  There are a few areas that are over and under it but you can't freeroam in it whatsoever.

Comment: @Shinrai: Yeah, but you still can enter it and destroy the titan crates and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can't enter the restricted area at all. The titan containers that you are referring to are most likely in the subway area that runs beneath it. You haven't unlocked the map of the subway yet but when you do you will understand. You can also go inside wonder city, but you can never freeroam in the restricted area.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the restricted area, but not from the sub way. It is possible by crossing the walls. This can be achieved by gliding and dive bombing enough to fly higher and crossing the wall. As soon as you get inside, Batman will be attacked by sentry guns.

I immediately left the location when this happened.